# Removing Sitecore 9.3 xp scale topology App service from azure

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, publishing, reporting

As i compare one of my Sitecore 10 instance XP-scale topology and i didn't find below two app services in azure
1)svc-pub 2) svc-rep

My question is -> If i removed above two azure app services from my Sitecore 9.3 XP-scale topology what is the impact ?

Answer (score 1):

By removing **svc-rep** from a Sitecore 9.3 XP (distributed) environment, you will lose the reporting functionality. This will result in errors showing in the dashboard when trying to view things (such as experience analytics).

> In sitecore 10.1, the reporting role was combined with the content
> management role to reduce hosting costs. The xDB Reporting role has
> been combined with the Content Management role to reduce hosting
> costs.

[https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/what's-new/what-s-new-in-sitecore-10-1.html](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/what%27s-new/what-s-new-in-sitecore-10-1.html)

The **svc-pub** role will either be a CM role that is dedicated to publishing, or the publishing service (I am unfamiliar with what is deployed by default in azure service).

By removing this you may lose the ability to publish new content, in which case you may need to tweak config on your CM instance to re-enable publishing. However, you may find that by removing the dedicated instance, the CM instance picks it up automatically (you would need to test this out).